# Getting error while using PIVOT

Tags: sql, database, pivot-table, rdbms

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT YEAR(CreateDate) [Year],
              MONTH(CreateDate) [Month],
              DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate) [Month Name],
              COUNT(id) [Transaction Count],
              CASE
                  WHEN PaymentStatus =  1 THEN 'Pending'
                  WHEN PaymentStatus =  2 THEN 'Commited'
                  WHEN PaymentStatus =  3 THEN 'Confirmed'
                  WHEN PaymentStatus =  4 THEN 'Canceled'
                  WHEN PaymentStatus =  5 THEN 'Failed'
                  ELSE ''
              END AS PaymentStatus,
              COUNT(id) as counts 
       FROM [dbo].[BankPaymentRequest]
       GROUP BY YEAR(CreateDate),
                MONTH(CreateDate),
                DATENAME(MONTH, CreateDate),
                PaymentStatus
     ) AS asd
PIVOT( SUM(counts)
       FOR PaymentStatus IN ( [Pending],
                              [Commited],
                              [Confirmed],
                              [Canceled],
                              [Failed]
                            )
     ) AS MNamePivot
```

[Having some multiple rows for same months, only 12 months should display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHsr8.png)

Comment: I want to display only Unique month with respect of count of pending, commited, Confirmed, canceled and failed transaction count.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please post expected result, tag DBMS

Comment: Please edit the question to contain all information, not in comments. Also, formatting.

Comment: In your Question you state how you *do not* wish for your results to appear.  Please show how you *do* wish for your results to appear.  Please support your sample output with sample data.

Comment: i want to get the result Month wise with respective of pending, confirm,cancel,committed and failed transaction count.